# дали список номеров автозапчастей которые есть в наличии, как их привязать к моделям и маркам авто?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

проблема 1, одна автозапчасть подходит к разным авто
проблема 2, "номера те что написаны на коробочке" т.е. я знаю номер и производителя, но это не OEM номер запчасти.

мне надо сделать выбор детали по машине, марке, году выпуска и категории автозапчасти.

Comment: Скорее всего, просто одной категорией автозапчасти Вы не обойдетесь. Тут дерево деталей. Для лучшего понимания надо взять пару марок автомобилей разных производителей и попробовать внести их детали в БД чтобы понять какая структура потребуется.  Или Вам дали задание не только структуру таблиц разработать - но и заполнить реальными данными?

Comment: дали таблицу реальных данных остатков со склада, надо их разобрать по маркам авто, и по сути сделать автомагазин с подбором запчастей по маркам и моделям авто, из того что есть на складе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
    if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
        echo "Got Irix";
    }
    if (in_array("mac", $os)) {
        echo "Got mac";
    }
?>
```

Comment: что то около этого и сделал :)